# How To Capture "Row" Number

Tags: clojure

My question is how can I capture the index of the vector row where a match occurred? In the code below, what am I doing wrong?

I have a vector of vectors

`(def v1 [[44 2 3 4 5][1 6 7 5 10][11 12 13 14 15]])`

a column index, and a comparison value

```
(def cmp-val1 11)
(def col-idx 0)
```

I want to return the row index where a comparison returned true. With col-idx = 0 and cmp-val1 = 11, I should see (first row-num) return 2, and it is returning 1.

```
(defn ret-match-row
    "Return the index of the row, in which the cmp-val is found.
     It is okay to increment 0."

    [in-seq cmp-val col-idx]

    (let [rn 0]
        (let [row-num
            (for [seq-row in-seq
                    :let [local-row-num (inc rn)]
                    :when (= cmp-val (nth seq-row col-idx nil))]

                local-row-num)]

            (first row-num))))
```

From lein repl:

```
bene-csv.core=> (ret-match-row v1 cmp-val1 col-idx)
1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'll try these out tomorrow. It's funny that I've seen more comments saying loop .. recur is very low level and to use sequences, but loop .. recur always seems a more logical way to solve problems like this. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: loop/recur works well here because you are relying on indices, you have to give up on indices as much as possible (which may require a shift in the way you model your data) to leverage Clojure's style of FP.

Comment: @cgrand Even with the excellent answers here, I'm basically looking to shorten the solution, and loop .. recur does that for me. The set solution has an advantage of allowing multiple compares, but I have to give up in which column I searched. That's OK with unique database keys, but I' relying on user-generated insurance reports that could and probably will contain the results of "cockpit" error.

Comment: Thanks again for your comments @cgrand I'm figuring a way to filter out all the non-matches, so my mind is shifting, just not hoping for a San Andreas Fault sized shift. :)

Comment: is your vector of vector a resultset of a db query? Isn't there already a key for each row? Please give more context.

Comment: @cgrand My sequence of sequences is the result of reading two .csv files, one is our vendor's idea of who is enrolled in health insurance, and the other is our idea of who is enrolled. Both .csv files are parsed by clojure-csv. I want to take a key in col n of one report and look in col y of another report to see if the key (ssn) is there. If not, I will look in a second column of the same "other" report to see if it's there.

Comment: @cgrand I commented after the answers, because I am seeing a "sequence" way to solve the problems. I had to walk away from the problem for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other ways to do what your'e asking, but you can use a loop/recur to achieve the iteration you're after:

```
(defn ret-match-row [rows val col-idx]                                                                              
  (loop [[row & rows] rows                                                                                          
         pos 0]                                                                                                     
    (cond                                                                                                           
      (not row)                                                                                                     
      nil                                                                                                           
      (= val (nth row col-idx))                                                                                     
      pos                                                                                                           
      :not-found                                                                                                    
      (recur rows (inc pos)))))                                                                                     

(ret-match-row [[44 2 3 4 5]                                                                                        
                [1 6 7 8 10]                                                                                        
                [11 12 13 14 15]]                                                                                   
               11                                                                                                   
               0)                                                                                                   

;; => 2
```

You're also running into Clojure's immutability - the (inc rn) is not actually modifying rn.  The loop / recur solution uses inc as well, but it passes the result of inc to the next iteration of the loop.

Clojure's for (list comprehension) form also will loop over all of the values in the sequence, resulting in a new sequence -- which is most likely not what you want.  Even if you made the for loop do what you want, it will find all the matches, not just the first.  The loop / recur example stops at the first match.

Answer (score 3):

```
=> (defn ret-match-row
      [coll cmp idx]
      (keep-indexed (fn [i v] (if (= cmp (get v idx)) i)) coll))

=> (ret-match-row v1 11 0)
(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

A flexible answer comes from separating this into three distinct problems and composing them.

- creating the data you seek
- finding the data you want
- presenting the way it should look.

---

first we number the rows by adding row numbers to them

```
(map vector v1 (range))
```

then filter out the rows not containing the number you want:

```
(filter (fn [[data index]] (some #{11} data)) (map vector v1 (range)))
> ([[11 12 13 14 15] 2])
```

here i used the trick that sets are functions that test their input for inclusion in the set which allows this to test for multiple values:

```
(filter (fn [[data index]] (some #{11 44} data)) (map vector v1 (range)))
> ([[44 2 3 4 5] 0] [[11 12 13 14 15] 2])
```

then since you only want to know where it matched and not what matched we filter that out:

```
(map second (filter (fn [[data index]] (some #{11 44} data)) (map vector v1 (range))))
> (0 2)
```

---

to wrap this into a nice function we write out the steps:

```
(defn with-row-numbers [col] (map vector col (range)))
(defn find-my-rows [rows goals] 
   (filter (fn [[data index]] (some (set goals) data)) rows)) 
(defn present-rows [rows] (map second rows))
```

and then compose them:

```
(defn ret-match-row [data rows]
  (-> data 
   (with-row-numbers) 
   (find-my-rows rows) 
   (present-rows)))

(ret-match-row v1 [11])
(2)
```

sorry i couldn't help making it work with multiple values, its a habit.

```
(ret-match-row v1 [11 15 44])
> (0 2)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Arthur Ulfeldt, this is a wonderful solution, but it loses the search column. The key could be, but should not be, in another column.

Answer (score 0):

My take, using 
clojure.contrib.seq find-first, indexed:

```
(defn ret-match-row [rows val col-idx]

(first 

(find-first #(= val (nth (second %) col-idx))

(indexed rows))))
```